# How to simply call a PYD from a wheel installed package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm building a pyd file via pybind11. There's no python-only code in the project (not even in the final wheel). I'm packing this prebuilt pyd into a wheel package. It's all working well so far, but I've got one small issue. Every time I want to use the functions from the pyd file (which is actually the primary "source" of code) I have to type the following: `from python_lib_name.pyd_name import pyd_exported_class` example: `from crusher.crusher import Shard`. This looks pretty lame, is there any way to prevent this and let the developer simply use the `from crusher import Shard` syntax?

Also, I'm not sure what information to provide, obviously, I wouldn't like to throw the whole project at you unnecessarily. I'm glad to provide any details by editing.

Comment: I guess your pyd need to include inside the equivalent of a `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this: put your pyd in a folder and include a `__init__.py` that import the stuff from the pyd

```
my_project 
 |---my_pyd_lib
 |   |---my_pyd_lib.pyd
 |   |---__init__.py
 |---#the other stuff
```

and in that init just put

```
#__init__.py
from .my_pyd_lib import *
```

the dot in the import make it a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) useful to make sure that import the thing in the same folder as that file, it also make sure you import your thing if it happens to share a name with some other package/module you happens to have installed

Comment: Wow. I didn't copypaste your answer and I was lost trying to replicate what you did for half an hour and I failed continuously. Then I realized you wrote an extra dot before the my_pyd_lib word. Using that things magically started to work. What does that extra dot mean? Where is it documented?

Comment: that is a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), so it start searching in same folder where the file live rather than the usual

Answer (score -1):

One way to make a pyd file simply importable is to use the Python interpreter's -m flag. For example, if your file is called foo.pyd and is located in the current directory, you can import it by running the following command:

python -m foo

This will cause the Python interpreter to load the module from foo.pyd and then execute its contents as if they were written in a normal .py file. You can also use this technique to import modules that are located in different directories; just specify the path to the module as an argument to -m.

Another way to make a pyd file simply importable is to convert it into a normal .py file.

Comment: Allright, maybe my title is confusing and misleading, sorry. But did you actually read my post as well?